# How do I use VBA to copy rows in Excel sheet and send them to a CSV?

Tags: excel, vba, csv, parsing

What I want to do is pretty simple, I just have literally 0 experience with VBA. I have experience coding in other languages though (java, js, c, etc.).

What I am trying to do is go through the rows of an excel sheet, see if the integer value in the first cell of each row is within a certain range, and if it is, then copy that entire row and paste it into a new sheet that will be saved as a CSV.

I am able to go through the column and check the first cell value in each row, I now need to know how to take that corresponding row, copy it, and paste it in the CSV sheet.

For example, say this is the excel sheet I am trying to parse:

[image]

Say the user specifies that they want to grab all rows where the value in the first cell of that row is between 3 and 9 (rows 6-8, 11, 13-15). My VBA code would then go through all the rows and grab only the rows that fit the criteria above, and then send those rows to a new sheet that would look something like this:

[image]

This is what my code looks like right now, which goes down Column A, and checks the value in first cell of each row. I am not sure how to grab each row, and then send it to the new sheet

```
Sub exportDesiredRowsToCSVSheet()

    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = "myCSV"
    MsgBox "Sheet 'myCSV' was created"     'create new sheet that I will save as CSV at the end
    
    
    firstL = Application.InputBox("first line item num", "please enter num", , , , , , 1) 'gets user to input lower bound
    lastL = Application.InputBox("last line item num", "please enter num", , , , , , 1) 'gets user to input upper bound

    
    For Each Row In Range("A:A")        'go through rows in column A
        For Each Cell In Row            'go through first cell in each row of column A
            If Cell.Value >= firstL And Cell.Value <= lastL Then    'if the value in the cell is in the range
                'Here I want to take the desired rows and copy/paste them to a the newly created 'myCSV' sheet
                
            End If
        Next
    Next
        
    

End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You only need one loop. You also should [find the last row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba).... `For Each cell in Range("A1:A" & lastRow)`. You may be able to just use `Range.AutoFilter` here instead of looping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your knowledge of VBA far exceeds mine of java etc.  The following basic code will do what you want - following on from @BigBen's suggestions regarding finding the last row & using a filter to copy all rows at once.

It assumes the code is in that workbook.  You'll need to add your own error traps for invalid user input.

**CODE EDITED AS PER OP's REQUIREMENTS**

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopyToCSV()
Dim LastRow As Long, FirstL As Integer, LastL As Integer

FirstL = InputBox("Pick the first Row number", "First Row Selection")
LastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'EDIT - maximum number in range selected automatically
LastL = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Sheet1.Range("A2:A" & LastRow))

'Left in case you change your mind
'LastL = InputBox("Pick the final Row number", "Final Row Selection")

'***************************************************
'You'll need to determine your own Error Traps here
'***************************************************

With Sheet1
    .Range("A:A").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">=" & FirstL, _
    Operator:=xlAnd, Field:=1, Criteria2:="<=" & LastL
End With

'Create new sheet rather than new csv workbook
ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets _
(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)).Name = "myCSV"

'Add new headers - change to suit
Sheets("myCSV").Cells(1).Resize(1, 5).Value = _
Array("NewH1", "NewH2", "NewH3", "NewH4", "NewH5")

'Copy to new sheet in this workbook assumes data is on sheet 1
'Copy values only (and formats?)
With Sheet1.Range("A2:A" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    .EntireRow.Copy
    Sheets("myCSV").Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    '*** UNCOMMENT THE NEXT LINE IF YOU ALSO WANT FORMATS COPIED ***
    'Sheets("myCSV").Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
End With

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Sheet1.AutoFilterMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! This is super close to what I was describing. Is it possible to have the rows that are grabbed get put into a new sheet within the same workbook as the original sheet rather than save it as its own workbook? Also, am I able to explicitly specify what I want the headers/titles in the first row of this new csv to be rather than copying the first row of the original sheet?

Comment: Code amended.  Please accept the answer if it now satisfies all requirements.

Comment: thank you for the help! One last question, your code seems to copy over the very first row in the original workbook along with the rows I want. How do I make it so it ONLY copies over the rows that fit the criteria?

Comment: It shouldn't do: `With Sheet1.Range("A2:A" & LastRow).` is starting from row 2 `A2`.  Can't really explain that one??

Comment: my mistake, I for some reason had A1:A, but I think I know why. If I do 'A2:A' , it doesnt have that additional row, but I actually need that additional row because if I don't some of the formulas used in the data I am moving don't work, the cells say !#REF. Do you know if there is a simple change to the code you put to make it so it copies the raw values from the cells rather than copying the data thats determined by a formula?

Comment: Code edited.  Note the line to un-comment if you also want the formats copied.  Tested  & works fine. :)

Comment: youre the man, thank you again for the help. 1 last question, when I specify the filter criteria

`With Sheet1`
    .`Range("A:A").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">=" & FirstL, _`
    `Operator:=xlAnd, Field:=1, Criteria2:="<=" & LastL`
`End With`
is there a way to instead of using an upper bound for criteria2, can I check to see if the value in the cell is a number (not blank or string)? I want to be able to have the user enter a lower bound and then automatically grab all rows that have a number that is equal or larger than the lower bound. Maybe some sort of isNumber built in method?

Comment: Code now determines maximum value in range.  NB Max() tends to ignore text, but dates are treated by Excel as numbers.

Comment: Thank you so much man, I really appreciate the help! Out of curiosity and for my own knowledge, what does the `Application.CutCopyMode = False` line at the end do?

Comment: It clears the Clipboard - I added it after we changed the `Copy` method to a `Paste` method.  Without it, Excel leaves the flashing lines around the area being copied, telling us that the selection is still in the Clipboard waiting to be pasted somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

### Copy with Criteria Using Loop

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub exportDesiredRowsToCSVSheet()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const srcName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const dstName As String = "myCSV"
    Const cCol As String = "A"
    Const FirstRow As Long = 2
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Define Source worksheet.
    Dim src As Worksheet
    Set src = wb.Worksheets(srcName)
    
    ' Determine min and max.
    Dim minID As Long
    minID = Application.Min(src.Columns(cCol))
    Dim maxID As Long
    maxID = Application.Max(src.Columns(cCol))
    
    ' Get user input.
    Dim FirstL As Variant
    FirstL = Application.InputBox("First line item number", "Enter Number", _
        minID, , , , , 1)
    If FirstL = False Then
        MsgBox "User canceled."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim LastL As Variant
    LastL = Application.InputBox("Last line item number", "Enter Number", _
        maxID, , , , , 1)
    If LastL = False Then
        MsgBox "User canceled."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Determine rows.
    FirstL = Application.Match(FirstL, src.Columns(cCol), 0)
    If IsError(FirstL) Then
        FirstL = Application.Match(minID, src.Columns(cCol), 0)
    End If
    LastL = Application.Match(LastL, src.Columns(cCol), 0)
    If IsError(LastL) Then
        LastL = Application.Match(maxID, src.Columns(cCol), 0)
    End If
    If LastL < FirstL Then
        maxID = FirstL
        FirstL = LastL
        LastL = maxID
    End If
    
    ' Define Destination worsheet.
    Dim dst As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set dst = wb.Worksheets(dstName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not dst Is Nothing Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        dst.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
    Set dst = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
    dst.Name = dstName
    
    ' Copy form Source to Destination worksheet.
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim dRow As Long
    src.Rows(1).Copy dst.Rows(1)
    Set rng = src.Range(src.Cells(FirstL, cCol), src.Cells(LastL, cCol))
    dRow = 1
    For Each cel In rng.Cells
        If cel.Value > 0 Then
            dRow = dRow + 1
            cel.EntireRow.Copy dst.Rows(dRow)
        End If
    Next cel
    
    ' Save as '.csv'.
    dst.Move ' or 'dst.Copy' if you wanna keep a copy in Source workbook.
    With ActiveWorkbook
        '.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & dstName, xlCSV
        '.FollowHyperlink ThisWorkbook.Path ' Show in windows explorer.
        '.Close
    End With
    
    'wb.Save
    
    ' Inform user.
    MsgBox "'" & dstName & "' was created", vbInformation

End Sub
```